# Code snippet for comparing hashes with similar keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I am writing integration tests for rails and I want to compare the object created with the JSON object sent. The object returned is not exactly the same as the one sent, (i.e.) it has keys that the object sent doesn't have because I am using active model serializers to pull associations in the returned object. Basically, I just want to compare all the same keys between both objects to see if its the same. Let me know if there is a clean efficient code snippet that does this for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Hash#slice`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice), which is an Active Support core extension.

For example, if the keys you want to check are `:a, :b, :c`, but the result contains `:a, :b, :c, :d`, `slice` will reduce the result to just contain the keys you care about:

```
expected = { :a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3 }
result   = { :a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3, :d => 4 }

result.slice(:a, :b, :c) == expected
# => true
```

If you get a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'slice'` exception, you need to require `active_support/core_ext/hash/slice`

Comment: For Active Support core extensions, it's really useful to include a link to the Core Extensions document, which tells how to cherry-pick just to needed methods, not include everything that Active Support offers. See "[Active Support Core Extensions](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html)".

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

"Clever" test code is rarely useful. Each test should be as simple as possible, and it should be testing the behavior of some object rather than its composition. There are always ways to be clever, though.

### Using Array Intersection

One unreadably-clever way to do this is to use [Array#&](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-26) to find the intersection of the keys, and then look for equality between the values. This will work on a relatively flat hash. For example:

```
hash1 = {:key1=>"value1", :key2=>"value2", :key3=>"value3", :key4=>"value4"}
hash2 = {:key1=>"value1", :key2=>"value2", :key5=>"value5"}
Array(hash1.keys & hash2.keys).map { |k| hash1[k] == hash2[k] }.uniq
#=> [true]
```

If you're using RSpec to test, you could say something like:

```
it 'has some matching key/value pairs' do
  # ... populate hash1
  # ... populate hash2
  Array(hash1.keys & hash2.keys).
    map { |k| hash1[k] == hash2[k] }.uniq.should == [true]
end
```

Of course, if the expectation is false, then you won't really know why, or which key/value pair was wrong. This is just one of the many reasons that you should always use fixed inputs and outputs for testing, rather than trying to do dynamic comparisons.

Comment: I ***completely*** agree with your opening statement.  The only qualification is that what seems clever to one developer may be second nature to another.  But the point is an important one nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

First, find the keys that both hashes contain, and then compare the value for those keys:

```
hash1 = {:key1 => "value1", :key2 => "value2", :key3 => "value3", :key4 => "value4"}
hash2 = {:key1 => "value1", :key2 => "value2", :key5 => "value5"}

hash1_keys = hash1.keys
hash2_keys = hash2.keys

comparable_keys = hash1_keys.select{|key| hash2_keys.include?(key)}

comparable_keys.each do |key|
  hash1[key].should == hash2[key]
end
```

Comment: This is kinda what I already have but I thought since this ruby, there might be some cool one-two line code which does the same thing but thanks!